# Google Storage Object Versioning with Cloud CDN Caching

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cdn

Google Cloud CDN recommended to use versioned URL for static objects.

If I enabled Google Storage versioning, could the Cloud CDN get the fresh one instead of the cache one (prior to its normal expiration time) after updating an obeject on Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the cache system (in the CDN or elsewhere) prevent any extra communication until the cache expire.

By the way, the cache system will never ask the backend before the cache expiration. In addition, Cloud Storage isn't aware that an additional layer catch its data and store them for a period of time.

By design, it's no, versioning change nothing in the CDN cache management.